# Boot into EFI Shell

Tags: boot, uefi, efi

I am trying to boot into the EFI shell on my ACER VERITON MG2640G. I have tried the following without success:

- I have pressed some F-keys when starting the computer. This will open the Windows-Start-Manager.
- I have tried to access the EFI shell from bios, but there appears to be no option to do so (e.g. there is no "boot manager" option in the bios menue).
- I have created a bootable USB following [these instructions](https://github.com/chipsec/chipsec/wiki/Creating-a-Bootable-USB-drive-with-UEFI-Shell). However, the USB drive does not seem to be recognized as a bootable device.

How can I access the EFI shell on my computer?

Comment: Do you know whether your computer actually _has_ the EFI Shell built in? Most manufacturers don't bother including it (perhaps to save flash space), in which case options 1 and 2 couldn't possibly work.

Comment: Can you boot into windows? (assuming you run windows?) If so, from within windows, reboot, but hold shift as you click on the restart option. This will boot you into the recovery menu, from which you can boot into UEFI mode if supported.

Comment: Also, your computer either has a BIOS (setup) or UEFI. Not both. If you can get in either of them, the other does not exist on your computer.

Comment: @user1686 is there a way to find out whether a shell has been built in?

Comment: @LPChip I did boot into the recovery menu, but am not sure which option will get me to the EFI shell. I am able to access BIOS. So is there no UEFI available? In the BIOS boot option I can choose between UEFI and legacy.

Comment: Yes, if you can acces the BIOS, you have no EFI shell.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there any way to install one?